# How can I filter question with two different dates and tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to filter the question by `tag`, `score` and date. I want to check those questions which `tag` is `laravel` and whose are frequent from `October 2017` to `November 2017` with `score`. Is there any way to filter such kind of questions?

Comment: What exactly it is about https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching that you don't understand?

Comment: @RobertLongson this is so useful for me +1

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do the trick:

```
[laravel] score:1 created:2017-10 created: 2017-11
```

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) next time :)